# Meaning of "...lettered avenues notwithstanding"

Tags: meaning

A writer in The Atlantic, wrote this about gentrification :

> Gentrification has rendered Lower Manhattan, Harlem, and much of Brooklyn unrecognizable to the previous generations that called those neighborhoods home. The East Village of Jonathan Larson’s Rent is nonexistent, **lettered avenues notwithstanding**.

<sup>*Source: [The Role of the Artist in the Age of Trump](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2019/12/lin-manuel-miranda-what-art-can-do/600787/) by Lin-Manuel Miranda*</sup>

I'm not sure of the meaning of "lettered avenues notwithstanding".

Answer (score 3):

The writer is making the point that gentrification has changed those neighborhoods.  Their ethnic, economic, and social makeup has changed from what it was earlier.  All that remains of what once was, are the lettered avenues, *Avenue A, Avenue B, and Avenue C*.

The neighborhoods Larson describes in Rent are gone.  All that remains are the lettered avenues.

Comment: To be very clear, "lettered avenues" has no generic meaning outside this context. It literally refers to "those avenues in Lower Manhattan which have letters instead of names."

Answer (score 0):

*Notwithstandind* is not a word - you mean *notwithstanding*.

I had to look this up, but apparently the New York district of East Village has some avenues identified by letters of the alphabet rather than names. I take it that the writer is saying that Larson's version of the district is fictional, even though he uses a real name and real street names.